# Rolling a dice and calculating frequency

Tags: python-3.x

my goal is to create a dice rolling simulator where the users enters, "number of rolls, "sides on die", and amount of trials. Part of my code (the lower half about error and such are used from an class example). I need help on getting the relative frequency and experimental probability. Also the professor noted that to receive the same numbers as his, the random number generator uses the integer 237. Thank you.

```
import random

# Sets the number of faces on the dice we are rolling
# Set to 6 for a 6-sided dice, 20 for a 20-sided dice, etc
NumberOfFaces = int(input("How many sides?:"))

face = [] # create a list
# Set the number of elements in the list
for x in range(0, NumberOfFaces):
  face.append(0)

NumberOfRolls = int(input("How many rolls?:"))

for y in range(0, NumberOfRolls):
  # roll the dice with randrange, and then add one to that element of the list
  face[random.randrange(0, NumberOfFaces)] += 1

numberOfTrials = int(input('How many trials? Enter:'))

# print out how many times each face came up 
for z in range(0, NumberOfFaces):
    frequency = (("%d: %d") % (z+1,face[z]))
    #print(frequency)

relativeFrequency = [0, 0]
probability = [0,0]
error = [0,0]
for i in range(2, len(frequency)):
   relativeFrequency.append(frequency/numberOfTrials)
   probability.append(min(i-1,13-i)/36)
   error.append(abs(probability[i]-relativeFrequency[i]))
# end for


#print(relativeFrequency)
#print(probability)
#print(error)
print()


# print results
f1 = "{0:<10}{1:<22}{2:<22}{3:<22}"
f2 = 71*"-"
f3 = "{0:>3}       {1:<22.15f}{2:<22.15f}{3:<.15f}"
print(f1.format("Sum","Relative Frequency","Probability","Error"))
print(f2)
for i in range(2, len(frequency)):
   print(f3.format(i, relativeFrequency[i], probability[i], error[i]))
#end for
print()
```

My desired output

```
Enter the number of dice: -1
The number of dice must be at least 1
Please enter the number of dice: 4
Enter the number of sides on each die: 1
The number of sides on each die must be at least 2
Please enter the number of sides on each die: 7
Enter the number of trials to perform: -1
The number of trials must be at least 1
Please enter the number of trials to perform: 10000
Sum Frequency Relative Frequency Experimental Probability
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 4 6 0.00060 0.06 %
 5 18 0.00180 0.18 %
 6 52 0.00520 0.52 %
 7 83 0.00830 0.83 %
 8 166 0.01660 1.66 %
 9 273 0.02730 2.73 %
 10 346 0.03460 3.46 %
 11 469 0.04690 4.69 %
 12 630 0.06300 6.30 %
 13 738 0.07380 7.38 %
 14 836 0.08360 8.36 %
 15 930 0.09300 9.30 %
 16 930 0.09300 9.30 %
 17 985 0.09850 9.85 %
 18 844 0.08440 8.44 %
 19 737 0.07370 7.37 %
 20 589 0.05890 5.89 %
 21 526 0.05260 5.26 %
 22 326 0.03260 3.26 %
 23 238 0.02380 2.38 %
 24 124 0.01240 1.24 %
 25 86 0.00860 0.86 %
 26 49 0.00490 0.49 %
 27 13 0.00130 0.13 %
 28 6 0.00060 0.06 %
```

Here is a link to the picture for accurate look of it

Desired Output

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific step you need help with? It is not clear from your question what the community can do to help you out.

Comment: I'm confused on getting the relative frequency and experimental probability

Comment: Are there things that you have already tried? It seems like the "Frequency" is the total number of times N dice add up to be a certain number. Then "Relative Frequency" is that Frequency number divided by the number of trials. Finally, the Experimental Probability seems to be that number multiplied by 100, to convert it to a percentage. For example, in your sample data, the Sum "10" was rolled 346 times. 346/10000 total rolls = .0346. Then converting that to a percentage is .0346 * 100 = 3.46%

Comment: I get an error : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

for the relativeFrequency portion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the difference between "expected" and "observed". If the random number generator is supposedly uniform, we expect each die to be fair. Assuming more than one die and the results added, expected distribution is a bell curve. The formula is given by our mathematical cousins, here

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010729/when-rolling-multiple-dice-what-is-the-average-value-if-you-only-keep-the-highe

It's a bit tricker than elementary maths, but not all that complicated.

To test if the trial is fair, you need to do a chi-squared tested between observed and expected results.